# What are the coordinates of a display object that has been transformed with a PerspectiveProjection?

Tags: apache-flex, transform, perspectives

I'm currently transforming some objects to make them appear far away using a `PerspectiveTransform`. This works well, but I have no way of knowing where on the screen the object is displayed. The x and y coordinates are the coordinates of the object if it were at `z=0`. How can I compute the display coordinates of my component?

Answer (score 0):

What about the [`flash.display.DisplayObject`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/DisplayObject.html)'s [`localToGlobal`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal()) and [`globalToLocal`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal()) methods?  Each takes a point from the first space and returns a transformed point in the second space.

EDIT:

Also see the [`local3DtoGlobal`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#local3DToGlobal()) and [`globalToLocal3D`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal3D()) methods for 3D transformations.